# pandas how to insert value from another row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'fruit': ['pear','pear','banana', 'pear', 'pear','apple', 'apple', 'cherry','cherry'],
        'fruit_type': ['unknown','pear','unknown', 'unknown', 'pear','unknown', 'apple', 'cherry','unknown'],
'country': ['unknown','usa', 'unknown', 'unknown','ghana','unknown', 'russia', 'albania','unknown'],
'id': ['011','011','011', '011', '011','011', '011', '6','6'],
'month': ['unknown','march', 'unknown', 'unknown', 'january','unknown', 'march', 'january','unknown']       
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['fruit','fruit_type','country', 'id', 'month'])
```

[image]

I want to fill rows where is unknown with value from another row for each group by `id`:

If we have an `unknown` value in the `month` column in the first place in the group by `id` we need to insert `unknown` values from the next row

If an `unknown` value in the `month` column not in the first place in the group by `id` we need to insert `unknown` values from the previous row

Can anyone see the problem?

Output dataframe:

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `replace()` for replacing 'unknown' to `NaN` then groupby 'id' and then forward fill and then backword fill and filnally assign the result back to df:

```
df=df.replace('unknown',float('nan'))
#If above replace doesn't work then use:
#df=df.replace('unknown',float('nan'),regex=True)
df=df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x:x.ffill().bfill())
```

output of `df`:

```
   fruit    fruit_type  country     id      month
0   pear    pear        usa         011     march
1   pear    pear        usa         011     march
2   banana  pear        usa         011     march
3   pear    pear        usa         011     march
4   pear    pear        ghana       011     january
5   apple   pear        ghana       011     january
6   apple   apple       russia      011     march
7   cherry  cherry      albania     6       january
8   cherry  cherry      albania     6       january
```

Comment: @jezrael how sir?pls tell!!

Comment: seems OK, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `unknown` to missing values and then forward and backward missing values per groups:

```
f = lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()
df = df.replace('unknown', np.nan).groupby(df['id']).transform(f)
print (df)
    fruit fruit_type  country   id    month
0    pear       pear      usa  011    march
1    pear       pear      usa  011    march
2  banana       pear      usa  011    march
3    pear       pear      usa  011    march
4    pear       pear    ghana  011  january
5   apple       pear    ghana  011  january
6   apple      apple   russia  011    march
7  cherry     cherry  albania    6  january
8  cherry     cherry  albania    6  january
```